# JavaScript not working in OpenERP 7 form view

Tags: jquery, odoo

I'm trying to create a jQuery code inside a form in OpenERP 7
I'm calling the function via the script tag on the XML view,

**I want to** trigger the code when user is clicking any cell(<td>) in a table ,
**but** the code doesn't trigger when I click the cell on the form's normal view,
 
**and I must** click edit button or create button and then click the cell(<td>) again to make it work ,
**Why ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write your code in a .js file and put it in a custom module.

Here a script i create. It create a box when cursor is over an event in a calendar:

in myModule/static/js/test.js file:

```
$(function() {
        $( document ).tooltip({
            items: ".dhx_cal_event, .dhx_cal_event_line, .dhx_cal_event_clear",
            open: function( event, ui ) {ui.tooltip.click(function() {$(this).hide();});},
            content: function() {
                var element = $( this );
                if ( element.is( ".dhx_cal_event" ) ) {
                    return $( this).children( ".dhx_title").text()+"  "+$( this).children( ".dhx_body").text();
                }
                else{return text = element.text();}

            }
        });

    });
```

};

in myModule/**openerp**.py file

```
{
    'name': 'myModule',
    'version': '1.0',
    'category': 'Project Management',
    'description': """
What your module do.
    """,
    'author': 'You',
    'js': [
        'static/src/js/test.js'
    ],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
    'sequence': 500,
}
```